# Both 'If' and 'Else' are executed in my windows batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

When I try to execute below batch file, the folder, *(reading input from user:foldername)*, is created, but the `else` steps are also getting executed, showing an error message.

> ```
> Enter a folder name:abc
> abc created succesfully
> 'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> abc already exist, choose other name
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

What is wrong with the code?

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@color 0a
cls

set "dest=D:\auto\Practice_3\destination"
set /p foldername=Enter a folder name:
set folder_date=%DATE:/=%
SET dirname="%folder_date:~8,4%_%folder_date:~6,2%_%folder_date:~4,2%"

mkdir %dest%\%USERNAME%\%dirname%

if not exist "%dest%\%USERNAME%\%dirname%\%foldername%" (
    mkdir %dest%\%USERNAME%\%dirname%\%foldername%
    echo %foldername% created succesfully
)
else (
    echo %foldername% already exist, choose other name
    pause
    exit
)
echo Listed files in file_list.txt are being copied ... 
echo Please wait ...
for /f %%f in (file_list.txt) do (

    for /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /S /B /A:-D "%%f"') Do (
                copy "%%F" "%dest%\%USERNAME%\%dirname%\%foldername%"       
    )
)
echo Backup done for listed files in file_list.txt
echo Tst and env files are being copied ...
echo Please wait ...

Set py_scripts="Python_Scripts"
mkdir %dest%\%USERNAME%\%dirname%\%foldername%\%py_scripts%
for /R %%f in (*.py) do copy %%f "%dest%\%USERNAME%\%dirname%\%foldername%\%py_scripts%"

pause

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: In the help file for the `IF` command, it clearly describes the correct syntax usage for using `ELSE`.  I am not sure where you found a working code example with the parentheses on a different line than the `ELSE`.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is in in the error output you've posted with your question:

```bat
'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

else must be on the same line as the closing parentheses of the `If` command.

```
) Else (
```